# How to calculate the time complexity of this recursive function?

Tags: recursion, time-complexity, big-o

I have the following recursive function with three calls that i need to find and prove the time complexity of

```
public static void fun(int [] arr, in x)
{
    if (x<=0)
        return arr[0];
    int m1 = fun(arr, x-1);
    int m2 = fun(arr, x-2);
    int m3 = fun(arr, x-4);
    if (m1>m2)
        return m1;
    else if (m2>m3)
        return m2;
    else
        return m1;
}
```

I know that the time complexity is Big-O(3^n) since it branches 3 times in each call but I am clueless how to prove it using math equations, I tried the Master theorem but some sources clam it only works for algorithms with two function calls, back substitution results in a large equation and the `arr[0]` causes confusion since i can't really tell what is the return value for the base case

Can anyone recommend a well-explain resource to understand how to calculate the time complexity for function with N function calls where N is any number larger than 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generalization of the Masters Theorem is called [Akra–Bazzi Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method).

However, the issue in your case is that the Masters Theorem only works for  recurrences of the form `f(n) = a f(n/b) + h(n)`. But in your case the recursive calls do not reduce the input by a constant factor and instead *subtract* a constant bit from it.

Anyway, the full  recurrence would be `f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2) + f(n-4) + 1`.
You can simplify it to `f(n) = 3 f(n-1) + 1` (as an upper bound) and `f(n) = 3 f(n-4) + 1` (as an lower bound) and just unroll the recurrence.
The first case gives you `3^(n-1) + 3^(n-2) + ... + 1` as an upper bound, the second one gives you `3^(n-4) + 3^(n-8) + ... + 1` as an lower bound.